# I can't show correct full screen mode in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, screen

When i hide SystemNavigationBar, i have show black line in the SystemStatusBar. How i can this is correct?

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky);
    return Container(
      color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Image(
            image: NetworkImage("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/flutterbricks-public.appspot.com/o/backgrounds%2Fyusuf-evli-bVq6bh26H-Y-unsplash.jpg?alt=media&token=770e26c4-a42a-4675-b978-5c34226a04fb"),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          )
        ],
      ),
    )
  }
```

used how buttons navBar as well as gestures navBar

i searched in answer in internet, but can not a search correct and need(